# Are laws of Physics same in frames having zero relative acceleration?

Tags: special-relativity, reference-frames, inertial-frames, relativity

If two frames have the same acceleration, then they'll be moving with a uniform speed with respect to each other. Are laws of Physics the same in these two frames?

Comment: Why did you assign tags about SR? Even in Newtonian physics the laws are the same. There is no preferred inertial frame. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galilean_invariance

Comment: The laws of physics are frame-independent, and therefore the same in all frames.

Comment: @G.Smith I'm talking about accelerated frames

Comment: Sorry, I didn’t read carefully enough.

Comment: Well, what do you think, and why?

Comment: @AaronStevens any of the frames don't seem to have anything special that the other frame doesn't have. Both are under the influence of the same force. So both should behave the same.

Comment: @tparker then why did Einstein specifically state 'inertial frame' in the first postulate?

Comment: @tparker Is probably talking in the context of GR

Comment: @AaronStevens Nope, I'm talking about SR as well, and all other physical theories. The laws of physics are the same in all frames, they just take more complicated mathematical forms in non-inertial frames.

Comment: @AaronStevens https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/350198/92058

Comment: @tparker Ok yes. I think the OP is asking if they would have the same mathematical form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The laws of physics are not frame dependent.  What is free dependent is the equations of motion.  And, indeed, we will find that the equations of motion will be the same in two frames that are accelerating the same.  You can do the frame transform and find that all vectors transform by the identity transform (other than position, of course)

This is true for "normal" equations of motion
If you embed some effect (such as an electrostatic repulsion) in the equation of motion rather than thinking of it as its own force, you obviously will see different forces at the same numeric coordinate in different frames